# integration area between two curves

Tags: calculus, integration

The diagram shows the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$. Given that the area of the shaded region is $72$, find the value of the constant $a$.

Graph for question:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

solve for $a$:

$$
\int_0^a \sqrt{x} dx =(a \sqrt a)-72
$$

can you do this?

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? check the picture. Your integral would give the other shaded area

Comment: If you want you can write $a\sqrt{a}-\int_0^a \sqrt{x}dx=72$, but it is the same! The kay fact is tha the integral is the area from the graph an the $x$ axis and the product $a\sqrt{a}$ is the are of the rectangle.

Comment: Ah. At first I didn't understand your writing. +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The total area is $A_T = a \cdot \sqrt a$. Now compute the area under the graph from $0$ to $a$. That is

$$\int_0^a \sqrt x dx$$

and solve for $a$  $$A_T - \int_0^a \sqrt x dx= 72 $$

Answer (score 1):

Just mentally flip the image around the $y=x$ axis and you've got the graph of $x=y^2$.

So solve $\int_0^w y^2\ dy = 72$ for $w$.

Then $w^2=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Approximately all the answers gave the result for the shaded area under the curve and not over it.

Note that the shaded region is the area between the curve $y_0 = y(a)=\sqrt{a}$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ and using the definition of area between curves in the interval $[0,a]$ ($A$ denotes the area):

$$
A = \int_{0}^{a}{|y_0-\sqrt{x}|dx}
$$

From the problem statement $A=72$, so:

$$
72=\int_{0}^{a}{|\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x}|dx}\\
72 =\int_{0}^{a}{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x} dx}\\
72 = {[x\sqrt{a}-\frac{2}{3}x\sqrt{x}]}_{0}^{a}\\
72 = a\sqrt{a}-\frac{2}{3}a\sqrt{a}\\
72 = \frac{a\sqrt{a}}{3}\\
a^3 = 216^2\\
a = 36
$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, but whatever... Here we go:

The gray shaded region has an area equal to:
$$
A=y(a)*a-\int_0^a\sqrt{x}dx=a^{3/2}-\frac23a^{3/2}=\frac13a^{3/2}
$$
You said that $A=72$, therefore $a=36$.

Cheers